# Imprimir elementos de un Array

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de imprimir los elementos que empujo a un array vacio en un li element desde un input cuando hago click en un boton, utilizando la funcion map.

El problema es que cada vez que agrego un elemento nuevo me imprime todo el array nuevamente.

Quisiera entender y saber como solucionarlo

Gracias

```
let myLeads = [];
let inputEl = document.querySelector("#input-el");
let ulEl = document.querySelector("#ul-el");


let printBtn = document.querySelector("#print-btn");
let inputBtn = document.querySelector("#input-btn");

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault;
    let inputValue = inputEl.value;
    myLeads.push(inputValue);
    console.log(myLeads)

});


printBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault;

    myLeads.map((lead) => {
      let newList = document.createElement("li");
      ulEl.appendChild(newList);
      newList.innerText += lead 
    })   
})
```

Comment: saca el + a newList.innerText += lead (newList.innerText = lead)

Comment: Quiza me exprese mal. 
Hay un boton que es para hacer el push al array del valor ingresado en el input. 
Y hay otro que es para imprimirlo en el browser dentro de un list element. 
El problema es que cada vez que quiero imprimir me repite todo el array. Yo quiero no imprimir los elementos ya impresos.

Comment: Tu quieres entrar pepe, ingresarlo, entrar juan, ingrsarlo, apretar imprimir y q t arme una lista con pepe y juan. Acto seguido entras maria y mandas a imprimir y te pone pepe,juan,pepe,juan,maria? Si es ese tu error saca el + como te dije

Comment: Claro pero sacando el  + igualmente me repite pepe y juan. Yo no quisiera que se repitan esos nombres que ya se inglresaron.. Seguro tenga que usar alguna otra funcion... Pero no sabria bien cual y como... Quizas un reduce y que el contador haga el chequeo si el nombre ya esta dentro del array.. Tengo la idea pero no se como aplicar la logica.

Comment: no entiendo bien seria simplemente reiniciar myLeads=[]??

Comment: @nestdan no, porque myleads es el array que contiene lo que va ingresando. Lo que hay que reiniciar es el ul que contiene las listas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui te pongo el codigo, dime si es esto lo que buscas:

```js
let myLeads = [];
let inputEl = document.querySelector("#input-el");
let ulEl = document.querySelector("#ul-el");


let printBtn = document.querySelector("#print-btn");
let inputBtn = document.querySelector("#input-btn");

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault;
    let inputValue = inputEl.value;
    myLeads.push(inputValue);

});


printBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault;

    ulEl.innerHTML = ""; //limpia lo que hay en la lista

    myLeads.map((lead) => {
     let newList = document.createElement("li");
     ulEl.appendChild(newList);
     newList.innerHTML = lead 
    })
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-el">
 <button id="input-btn">Ingresar</button>
 <button id="print-btn">Imprimir</button>
 <ul id="ul-el"></ul>
```

Solo tienes que sacar el mas y se me habia olvidado de ponerte que tambien debes limpiar el ul antes de volver a imprimir

Comment: Eso es lo que estaba buscando, Hernán. Muchas gracias. 
Quisiera entender bien porque ahora no me duplica los elementos. 
Entiendo que ` ulEl.innerHTML = "" ` vacia la lista completa, pero por otro lado el array sigue alojando los elementos y la funcion map, encargada de hacer la impresion, sigue recorriendo el array.

Comment: Pero quieres que tambirn se limpie el array? No tendria mucho sentido, pero si quires eso debes agregar myLeads = [] una vez que hagas print

Comment: No no perdón, Hernan. Solo quería entender bien como se solucionó.